Is Sentiment Analysis / News Analysis of Stocks considered on-topic?
I wonder if Financial aspects of data mining/ Sentiment Analysis / "News Analysis" are considered on topic here? For example this paper's 
material

If this is a research-level topic or something you actually do in the course of your work, then it could be. If the question is "How can I go about applying machine learning algorithms to stock markets?", or some other broad beginner-ish question, then no.
